# How to make a WPF app not to overwrite the files it creates

Tags: c#, wpf

The program below creates a snapshot of itself by pressing the P key. It creates the file in the directory the program is in. For example the first time you press the P key it creates the file snapshot.png, if you press it again it creates snapshot_1, third time snapshot_2 and so on...

But if you close the program and start it again and those files are existing now in the directory, if now you press P key it overwrites them...

What I want is the program to check if the file that it tring to create exist, and if so, to try to create a file with the next number in the row.. and if that exist too, then try the next, and so on, untill it finds a file name that not exist and only then to create the file.

Can you help me modify the code to do what i'm describing?

```
     string filename = "\\screenshot.png";
    private void Mainwindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {                     
        if (e.Key == Key.P)
        {

            FrameworkElement element = UxVisual as FrameworkElement;

            var pathstr = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

            filename = "\\screenshot_" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".png";
            Uri path = new Uri(pathstr + filename);


            CaptureScreen(element, path);
        }
```

Comment: append the date and time to the filename?

Comment: Is this homework? Do you understand why the program overwrites the files?

Comment: @fstam It sound like an elegant solution, and no need to add increasing numbers to the file name... can you please modify the code i posted to add date and time and not increasing numbers?

Comment: @tool can you send me part of your salary for that? DM me for my bank info. /s

Comment: @ardila It's not a home work, It's a project I'm doing for myself... and learn what i can in the process, I think I understand why it overwrites... because when the program restarts, it has a starting point already set... the directory of the program + snapshot.png

Comment: @fstam I'm afraid i will not make any money out of it... I'm unemployed:)

Comment: @tool we're not a free coding service. You'll have to try something. If you understand why it doesn't work the way you want and have a clear idea of how it should behave, then it should't take too much work to change the program, use the debugger and come up with a working solution. You can modify your question and ask about specific issues where you might get stuck.

Comment: If you're delivering this to a user there is a potential issue. You need to write to appdata rather than where an exe is usually installed. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30915.c-local-files.aspx

Comment: @Andy Thanks for the suggestion, the program i'm making has no installation... it's just an exe file that is meant to run from the desktop or from a folder in the desktop, I have no issues creating files in the desktop so far with the machine is making the program.... I dont know whats gonna happen in another machine tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why this question turned out to be so offensive in the commentsection above...
However as other users already suggesteted you should consider to add a timestampt to your filepath.
You can do this using `DateTime` and a string operation like this:

```
filename = "\\screenshot_" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".png";
```

possible output would be a file named `screenshot132006693766467910.png` this will cause all filenames to be different from ech other and not to overwrite each other

as requested you can make it look a lit better using this:

```
var filename = "\\screenshot_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH_mm_ss_fff") + ".png";
```

output will be like `screenshot_16_14_11_523.png` containing the hour minute second and milliseconds

Comment: I modified the code in the original post, please take a look, it works the way you predict, although that long sequence of numbers looks kinda ugly... it never overwrites... is there any way to reduse its length?

Anyway thank you very much for your time.

Comment: added a line to my answer so the result is a little easier on the eye now its is unlikly for one file to be overwritten but not impossible. If this helps you out please mark it as answer for others to find it if they need it